# Is there a way around restarting my MVC dev server every time I add an asset?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, web-essentials

In order to add an asset to my ASP.NET MVC project in Visual Studio, I have to stop my debug server, add the file, and then restart the server. However, once Visual Studio is aware of the file (an image, say), I can change its content using an external app and the debug server will serve up the changes just fine. The same thing applies to renaming files (i.e., you can't while the server is running). When working on a large content-driven site, this gets rather tedious and unproductive.

I presume this has to do with the way that files are packaged up into an assembly in MVC for deployment (by contrast to Rails or local static site generators, where the files are just served off of the file system), so it's understandable. But I'm wondering if there any way around this limitation that would make local site development less cumbersome.

Comment: Oh fascinating. As best as I can tell, this gives all the functionality I want. Thanks! Any idea what mode this is running and what its purpose is?

Comment: Excellent. Thank you! If you would like to move your comment into an answer, I'd be happy to mark it as the correct one.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I've created an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start it without debugging using ctrl + F5

This will run the code without the debugger attached, which is how code will run in production. This will also have performance benefits. If you never need the debugger you can even put your project in release mode (instead of debug mode) for even better performance.